# Quasar Framework in Vue3 Dark Mode

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

I am using Vue3 with the Quasar Framework.
I made an icon which changes my application to dark mode, however this is a bit too dark for my taste, so I would make the background a little bit lighter. Quasar gives you the options to do so, however it doesn't seem to work. In my Login.Vue, I have the following:

```
<template>// div's and icon...</template>
<script>// code to toggle to dark mode...</script>
<style>
body.body--dark {
  background: #333333
}
</style>
```

This code does not work, even if I change background to 'yellow', it stays black.
Why doesn't code on Quasar to change background color is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling `background` on [`body.body--dark`](https://quasar.dev/style/dark-mode#how-to-style-your-app) does work on a page:

```html
// pages/Index.vue
<style>
body.body--dark {
  background: #333333;
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasar-set-dark-page-color?file=src%2Fpages%2FIndex.vue)

Or you can set a [Sass variable](https://quasar.dev/style/sass-scss-variables):

```
// src/css/quasar.variables.scss
$dark-page: #333333;
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasar-set-dark-page-color-giyyqv?file=src%2Fcss%2Fquasar.variables.scss)

Comment: is it possible to set different colors as sass vars for dark theme? like $positive-dark  : #21BA45 !default

Comment: and how to change icon color in default dark mode?